# Cholesky, Inverse, and Determinant when updating the diagonal of a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and assume its dimension $n$ is large. Let $I$ be the $n \times n$ identity matrix and $m \neq 0$ be a scalar. I'm interested in computing as many of the following as possible:

- det$(A + mI)$
- $(A + mI)^{-1}$
- $(A + mI)^{-1}B$, where $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix
- the Cholesky decomposition of $A + mI$,

I'd like to do this for many values of $m$. However, because $n$ is large, I'd like to know if there is some update trick based on det$(A)$, $A^{-1}$, and the Cholesky decomposition of $A$. $A$ will likely not be sparse. I've been researching this for quite a while and the results haven't been all that encouraging.

Any help, hints, suggestions, or references would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have much hope either. You can precompute the SVD of $A$ which renders the first three easy, of course.

Comment: If you're using python, [scikit-sparse cholmod](https://scikit-sparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cholmod.html) can compute the Cholesky $L L' = A A'  + \beta I$ with parameter $\beta$. In C, I believe the underlying SuiteSparse can do that too, not sure.

Comment: [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that symetric positive definite matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix with positive elements. More specifically,
$$
P^{-1}AP = \operatorname{diag}\{a_1,...a_n\}
$$
where $a_i>0$ for $i \in [1, n]$, diag{$a_1,...a_n$} is diagonal matrix, and $P $ is invertible. So We have

\begin{align}
\det(A+mI)&=\det(P^{-1}(A+mI)P)
\\
&=\det(P^{-1}AP+P^{-1}(mI)P)
\\
&=\det(P^{-1}AP+mI)
\\
&=\prod \limits_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+m)
\end{align}

Since
$$
P^{-1}(A+mI)P = \operatorname{diag}(a_i+m)
$$
And
$$
\operatorname{diag}(a_i+m)^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(\frac{1}{a_i+m})
$$
where $a_i+m\neq0$

Thus
\begin{align}
(P^{-1}(A+mI)P)^{-1}&=P(A+mI)^{-1}P^{-1}
\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(a_i+m)^{-1}
\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(\frac{1}{a_i+m})
\end{align}

And

$$(A+mI)^{-1}=P\operatorname{diag}(\frac{1}{a_i+m})P^{-1}$$